# Ring Integration

Tags: calculus, integration, ring-theory, unification

In thinking about various methods of integration, I began to wonder if there was some sort of unifying theory relating integration and ring theory.

For example, would there be a way to make sense of something such as say integrating over a matrix ring? Or integrating over the ring of real quaternions?
We of course integrate over rings (viz. $\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{Q,Z}$ (trivial in the Lebesgue sense)) all the time, but I have wondered if there is a way to extend integration ever further to include more types of rings.

Are there examples of methods of integration that include integration over more abstract rings?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to integrate over rings? You might want to look into measure theory and the Haar measure.

Comment: With the appropriate measure on a group, we can have a satisfactory (and useful) theory of integration.

Comment: The general setting I'm aware of that does something like this is not for rings but for (locally compact topological) groups, for example the $+$ group of a ring. This is the theory of Haar measure: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_measure . An example of the application of this to a ring is Fourier analysis on the adele and idele groups of a number field, as in Tate's thesis: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tate%27s_thesis

Comment: Ah yes. The Haar Measure. Quite a nice thought.